# How can i handle multiple data type for a same key from API in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, types

Let's explain my problem..
suppose have a json object like

[from this picture i want to handle offer_price key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USIHw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz0rM.png)

```
 {
  "product": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 100.0,
      "offer_price": 40
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 80.0,
      "offer_price": 10.50
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "price": 200.0,
      "offer_price": "40.5"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "price": 100.0,
      "offer_price": null,
      
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the dart data model for `offer_price` field make its datatype as dynamic via which you'll be able to have a dynamic data in it as run type. And while  consuming this in any place just check the runtimeType of the variable and use it by type casting or just using it with `.toString()`.

eg class:

```dart
class Products {
  Products({this.product});

  Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['product'] != null) {
      product = <Product>[];
      json['product'].forEach((v) {
        product!.add(Product.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  
  List<Product>? product;
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (this.product != null) {
      data['product'] = this.product!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Product {
  Product({this.id, this.price, this.offerPrice});
  
  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    price = json['price'];
    offerPrice = json['offer_price'];
  }
  
  int? id;
  int? price;
  dynamic? offerPrice;


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['offer_price'] = this.offerPrice;
    return data;
  }
}
```

For consuming it just try:

```dart
Products products = List<Products>[];

//assign products = Products.fromJson(jsonData);

//using
products[i].offerPrice == null
? "null"
: products[i].offerPrice.runtimeType == String
   ? products[i].offerPrice.toString()
   : products[i].offerPrice.runtimeType == Int
      ? int.parse(products[i].offerPrice)
      : products[i].offerPrice.runtimeType == Double
           ? double.parse(products[i].offerPrice)
           : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product {
  int? id;
  int? price;

  // if you need the value as String
  String? offerPriceAsString;

  // Value as a double
  double? offerPrice;

  Product({this.id, this.price, this.offerPrice});

  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    price = json['price'];
    double.parse("1.0");
    // Any value to String
    offerPriceAsString = json['offer_price'].toString();
    // String to Double
    offerPrice = double.parse(json['offer_price'].toString());
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['price'] = price;
    data['offer_price'] = offerPrice;
    return data;
  }
}
```